# Горячие клавиши на jquery

Tags: jquery

Хочу при нажатии комбинации из <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>p</kbd> выполнить свой код на джейкуэри.
Допустим, пусть это будет алерт.

Собственно вопрос, как сделать это?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jquery Hotkeys. Вот [ссылочка](http://guide.avantajprim.com/?p=318)

Comment: а как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на определенные клавиши одновременно, он отображал свой символ?
например мы нажимаем "shift + f1" а он нам выбивает "‡"

У меня получилось с алертом

http://jsfiddle.net/vKrM9/137/


Помогите пожалуйста.